# Spring Lookup Method Injection failing with AbstractMethodError

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have a singleton service class like the below.

```
 @Service
 public class SingletonClass{

 @Autowired
 private ContextProvider provider;

 public Context run(){
 context = provider.createContext();
 updateContext(context)
}
```

ContextProvider class:

```
 public abstract class ContextProvider implements MyInterface{
        public abstract Context createContext(); 
}
```

configuration:

```
<bean name="provider"
        class="xyz.s.s.ContextProvider" >

        <lookup-method name="createContext"
            bean="someBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="somebean" class="com.x.y.someclass" />
<bean id="singletonService" class="com.x.y.SingletonClass" />
```

When i try to run the above using Junit ->instead of creating the lookup bean on demand, I am getting the below error

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
aused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)

It seems, the lookup method injection is not working in my case

Comment: Do you `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`?

Comment: Yes. is there any issue because of the Junit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and fixed it.

I was having the abstract class implemented an interface. So at run time, 
CGLIB unable to create a proxy class since there are unimplemented methods.

Compiler also did not complain, because this is abstract class and it did not expect us to add all implementations of the interface.

I removed the 'implements ' and it just works fine.

So the contextprovider will become,

```
public abstract class ContextProvider {
        public abstract Context createContext(); 
}
```

Posting this message, since people might face same situation.