# Java Spring: Can't seem to find local controller using @SpringBootApplication, @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I split my project into different repos, and now all of my endpoints are 404'ing (to be clear, they were working fine monolithically). I moved core code to another repository, and included it as an implementation through Gradle. I see it as an external dependency and not getting unresolved symbols or anything, so it seems fine dependency-wise.

Currently the application starts up seemingly fine, but when I try and hit endpoints they all 404:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-11-01T19:22:52.697+0000",
    "path": "/v1/location/ipv4/1.0.1.0",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": null,
    "requestId": "db040351"
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.projectname.location.api.controller;

import ...

@RequestMapping("/v1/location")
@RestController
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    private LocationService locationService;

    @GetMapping("/ipv4/{ip}")
    public Mono<Location> getLocationByIpv4(@PathVariable String ip) {
        return locationService.getLocationByIpv4(ip);
    }
}
```

Application:

```
package com.projectname.location;

import ...

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"projectname.core.location"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Without the `@ComponentScan` for the external library, the application will fail to start (`unsatisfied dependency`'s).

It seemed like the controller wasn't being included in the classpath (although according to my research, `@SpringBootApplication` should be doing that - is `@ComponentScan` overriding that?), so I tried adding to component scan:

`@ComponentScan({"com.projectname.location.api", "projectname.core.location"})`

```
                ^ trying to get local controller      ^ external core stuff
```

I've tried various paths, but all of them result in `unsatisfied dependency`'s or bean errors. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Stacktrace (occurs when I try and capture the local controller):

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'locationController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'locationService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'locationServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'locationRepository'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'locationRedisRepositoryImpl': Lookup
>   method resolution failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.projectname.location.core.repositories.LocationRedisRepositoryImpl]
>   from ClassLoader
>   [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4b85612c]

LocationRedisRepositoryImpl:

```
package com.projectname.location.core.repositories;

import ...

@Repository
public class LocationRedisRepositoryImpl implements LocationRepository {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveRedisOperations<String, Location> reactiveRedisOperations;

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory factory;

    public Mono<Location> getLocationByIpv4(Ipv4Request ipv4Request) {
        return reactiveRedisOperations.opsForValue().get(ipv4Request.getIpAddress());
    }

    public Mono<Boolean> writeLocation(Location location) {
        return reactiveRedisOperations.opsForZSet().add("ip-loc", location, Long.parseLong(location.getMaxIpInt()));
    }

    public Mono<RepositoryStatus> getStatus() {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    public Mono<Boolean> writeStatus() {
        return Mono.empty();
    }

    public Mono<String> flushAll() {
        return factory.getReactiveConnection().serverCommands().flushAll();
    }

}
```

LocationRepository:

```
package com.projectname.location.core.repositories;

import ...

@Repository
public interface LocationRepository {

    public Mono<Boolean> writeLocation(Location location);

    public Mono<Location> getLocationByIpv4(Ipv4Request ipv4Request);

    public Mono<RepositoryStatus> getStatus();

    public Mono<Boolean> writeStatus();

    public Mono<String> flushAll();
}
```

Comment: Can you try `@ComponentScan(basePackages="projectname.core.location")`?

Comment: same behavior with `basePackages` added

Comment: just try this `@ComponentScan({"com.projectname"})`

Comment: @Deadpool still get unsatisfied dependency error, i'll add the full stacktrace to the post

Comment: The problem is, it cannot find `LocationRedisRepositoryImpl`. Check your Redis connection. Could it be outside the packages we mention?

Comment: Redis connection seems to be fine. If I `git stash` my changes to revert it back to a monolithic application the endpoints work again.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it's related to `LocationRedisRepositoryImpl`. Can you share it? I'm OK if you change the actual package names, but please use the same alias for every replacement.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral added

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `@ComponentScan` in the very first place? `@SpringBootApplication` implicitly brings `@ComponentScan` into context. Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348280/spring-lookup-method-injection-failing-with-abstractmethoderror

Comment: if I don't use it it doesn't seem to find the stuff in the core repository? i get the same stacktrace listed in the description

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201744/discussion-between-hasan-can-saral-and-matt-takao).

Answer (score 1):

You have probably wrong configuration of component scan package. When you are using @SpringBootApplication, the @ComponentScan annotation is in your case redundant, because the SpringBootApplication annotation scans package where the class with this annotation is placed and its all sub-packages.

Also you have wrong package name in ComponentScan annotation - you wrote @ComponentScan({"projectname.core.location"}), but the correct package name should be @ComponentScan({"com.projectname.location"}).

So if you want to use the ComponentScan annotation, it should look like this (but the ComponentScan is redundant):

```
package com.projectname.location;

import ...

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.projectname.location"})
public class Application {

}
```